# How to display Chinese text in a window invoked by OpenCV's cvShowImage() function?

Tags: c++, xcode, image-processing, opencv

I want to add a Chinese text into the window title, which is invoked by the OpenCV's cvShowImage() function. But it does not give correct result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  const char *pstrFilename = "EDF001.png";
  const char *pstrWindowTitle = "欢迎来到细胞图像处理的世界！";

  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(pstrFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

  cvNamedWindow(pstrWindowTitle, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
  cvShowImage(pstrWindowTitle, img);

  cvWaitKey();

  cvDestroyWindow(pstrWindowTitle);
  cvReleaseImage(&img);

  return 0;
}
```

The result window:
[image: Incorrect Chinese text display on the Window title]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original comment was:

"If you use an English / ASCII name for the title, is it working fine? OpenCV might not be able to handle non-ASCII characters for the window caption."

But another potential solution is to use a *brute force* method in Objective C and with the Cocoa frameworks, such as:

```
NSWindow * openCVWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow];
if(openCVWindow)
{
    [openCVWindow setTitle: @"欢迎来到细胞图像处理的世界！"];
} else {
    NSLog( @"openCV's window isn't considered a main window!");
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works if I use the English name for title in OpenCV. I heard that OpenCV can display non-ASCII characters in Windows. Is that this problem caused by the OS X? Thanks.

Comment: Well, Macintosh windows can absolutely display Chinese characters, but the limitation here may be in the "`char *`" parameters to "`cvNamedWindow`" & "`cvShowImage`".  That's why I suggested the Objective C fix, which *might* work after you bring up and display the window.